# How to implement alpine component accessible on all pages of the app?

Tags: laravel, alpine.js

in my Laravel 8 / apline 2.8 / tailwindcss 2 app
I want to make alpine component which must be accessible on all pages of the site and I
want to use footer for this
My resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php has structure :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    ...
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    ...
</head>


<body class="flex flex-col min-h-screen">
    <header class="h-14 bg-red">
        @include('layouts.header')
    </header>
    <main class="flex-1">
        @yield('content')
        @yield('scripts')

    </main>
    <footer class="h-8 bg-green">
        @include('layouts.footer')
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

But Trying to implement footer comnponent  in resources/views/layouts/footer.blade.php :

```
    <div class="m-0 p-0">

        <div class="flex w-full p-0 m-0 content-center justify-between md:w-1/2 md:justify-end" x-data="adminFooterComponent()">
           ...

        </div>
    </div>


@section('scripts')

    <script>

        function adminFooterComponent() {
            console.log('adminFooterComponent::')

            return {
                addDonationOpen: false,
            }
        } // function adminFooterComponent() {

    </script>

@endsection
```

I got error :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: adminFooterComponent is not defined
```

I suppose that I got this error as I did not wrap(as I do on all my pages) my footer in

```
@section('content')
   ...
@endsection
```

section. But I really do not need it, as resources/views/layouts/footer.blade.php is a partial file.

How can I implement alpine component accessible on all pages of the app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue arises since the section is included in the footer. To resolve the issue, we can include the section in the actual view or we can just include it in the layout file itself.

1. Method 1 - In the blade file

```html
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    ......
@endsection


@section('scripts')

<script>
    function adminFooterComponent() {
            console.log('adminFooterComponent::')
            return {
                addDonationOpen: false,
            }
        }
</script>

@endsection
```

2. Method 2 - In layout file (directly) `app.blade.php`

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">

<head>
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.8.0/dist/alpine.min.js" defer></script>
</head>


<body class="flex flex-col min-h-screen">
    <main class="flex-1">
        @yield('content')
    </main>
    <footer class="h-8 bg-green">
        @include('layouts.footer')
    </footer>

    <script>
        function adminFooterComponent() {
                console.log('adminFooterComponent::')
                return {
                    addDonationOpen: false,
                }
            }
    </script>
</body>
```

The straightforward solution is Method 2 so that the code is not replicated.